# using the Lasso in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso, lars

I am a beginner, and I am trying to use the Lasso to do some regression.  I am looking specifically at the [LassoLars module in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoLars.html#sklearn.linear_model.LassoLars). What I am really after is recovering the parameter weight vector that is represented by `model.coef_`.  The trouble I am seeing that the weight vector always comes back as a zero vector.  Since this is an optimization problem without constraints I figured it should at least return some weights in the parameter for some test data that I'm using.

The objective function that I am tyring to model from the literature looks like this:
[image]

So i have assumed the the `y` vector in the Lasso objective function is represented by the rho * vector of ones ( where rho is the mean ).  Thats why I have y the way it is as all the same.

The question I have is, is this the right way to use the Lasso to minimize this objective function?

I put together this short example to show my issue. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array( [[ 5.98976150e-03, -1.20984151e-02, -1.22465812e-02, 3.18018512e-03,
  -1.75622040e-03, -1.42396473e-03, 1.50766424e-03, -3.35345720e-03,
   5.19307642e-03],
 [-3.37106026e-03, -6.89156129e-05, 4.81265968e-03, 5.60838622e-03,
   1.22018867e-02, -1.52073535e-02, -1.75285697e-02, -1.51518050e-02,
   2.40028354e-03],
 [-4.05015849e-03, 6.54103374e-03, -4.81555664e-03, 1.72384072e-04,
   5.54351348e-03, -7.61408621e-03, 3.45393320e-04, -1.55521027e-03,
   2.84937377e-03],
 [ 6.82272529e-03, -3.96931710e-03,  1.42365666e-03, -1.07870768e-02,
   3.29016538e-03,  5.47946576e-03, -1.84030370e-02, -6.61630991e-03,
   1.03000002e-02],
 [-5.59911877e-03, -2.04196233e-04, 2.90586730e-03, -1.16229772e-02,
   1.57885915e-02, -3.50405356e-03, -2.56087364e-02, -3.56488119e-02,
   2.97032595e-03]])
n = np.shape( X )[1]
y = [np.mean(X)] * n

from sklearn.linear_model import LassoLars
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

model = LassoLars(alpha = 1)
model.fit(X.T, y )
print( model.coef_ )
```

output: [0,0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 4):

`_coef` give you *parameter vector (**w** in the cost function formula)*. You should look at `y` vector.

```
y =  [-0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997, -0.0025973019854199997]
np.equal.reduce(y) # True
```

All the values are the same so you recive zeros vector.

To simplify you can imagine that you have two variable `X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])` and `y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])`.

```
lin = LinearRegression()
lin.fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), y)
print(lin.coef_) # array([0.])
```

Let's plot the data and result

[image: Plot]

Comment: I am trying to fit a model, and I am pretty sure that the y vector in this model is supposed to be the way you see it.  In the text it is actually represented by a constant times a vector of ones.  @RobJan

Answer (score 3):

## Issue 1

In addition to RobJan's answer, I think there is something unintended in your code:

`y = [np.mean(X)] * n`

This takes the mean of the whole matrix, and replicates it n times. What you might actually want is:

`y = np.mean(X, axis=0)`

where you actually get the mean of each column separately.

The fact that `y` was constant before (replicated X times) means that the optimizer could simply use a constant (the `intercept_`) , and didn't bother to tune the `coef_` according to `X`.

That's what Lasso does - avoids having unnecessary nonzero parameters.

## Issue 2

Trying to debug the model, I saw that `model.n_iter` was 0; which means it gave up instantly.
This led me to find out that `alpha` - the penalty term for the coefficient norm - was too big.

An `alpha` of 0.001 produced some nonzero `coef_`s for me.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I just tried the code with alpha set at 0.001 and much lower, I got zeros every time.  I had already tried adjusting the alpha, I'm thinking you may have changed another part of the code?

Comment: using `y = [np.mean(X)] * n` does allow the algo to get some real weights, but I have updated the question and you can see that I think the y vector is supposed to be a vector will all the same value.

Comment: The intercept comment was great, I set the fit_intercept param to False, and then I started seeing weights in the weight vector.